# Как сортировать массив, не используя сравнения?

Tags: java

Можно использовать ещё один массив. Знаю как реализовать пузырьковую сортировку:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("введите количество элементов");
    int num = s.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[num];
    System.out.println("введите элементы");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        a[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    int c;
    for (int x = 0; x < num - 1; x++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num - 1 - x; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                c = a[i];//c=a
                a[i] = a[i + 1];//a=b
                a[i + 1] = c;//b=c
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Но как отсортировать массив, не используя при этом сравнения?

Comment: Суть задачи в том, чтобы вы сами догадались, как избежать сравнений. И что означает фраза *"Массив от 0 до 5 ."*?

Comment: Что-то я не осознаю почему этот вопрос нужно минусовать. Если автор не знает алгоритма, то догадаться до него, на мой взгляд, не так и просто. И, сдаётся мне, далеко не все знают такой алгоритм.

Comment: Можно, например, организовать сито с перебором битовой маски 1000, 0100, 0010, 0001

Comment: @Regent у нас было прямо на контрольной это. Правда предполагалась сортировка подсчётом а не поразрядная, но это уже нюансы.

Comment: @pavel вот, кстати, не помню, чтобы в университете в курсе комбинаторных алгоритмов проходили эти алгоритмы. Может, я просто  пропустил это дело. Сортировку подсчетом писать не стал, потому что там бы пришлось вычислять мин. и макс. элементы, а как их вычислить без использования сравнения - не знаю. Да и при большом разбросе чисел памяти она отнимает немало.

Comment: @Regent да есть много читерных способов. Например MultiSet или аналог.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует [поразрядная сортировка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) ([radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)), которая используется для неотрицательных чисел. Её идея состоит в том, чтобы сортировать числа постепенно, по разрядам, с использованием корзин (buckets) для каждой цифры (от `0` до `9`).

1. Перебираем все позиции цифр в числе (в `Integer` их 10 штук).
2. Для каждой позиции проходим по всем числам в массиве и добавляем соответствующую этой позиции цифру числа в соответствующую этой цифре корзину.
3. После прохода по всем числам "собираем" массив обратно из чисел, хранящихся в корзинах, в том порядке, в котором они находятся в корзинах.

Реализация:

```
private static final int RADIX = 10;

public static void sort(int[] array)
{
    List<Integer>[] buckets = new ArrayList[RADIX];
    for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++)
    {
        buckets[i] = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    for (int placement = 1; placement <= 1000 * 1000 * 1000; placement *= RADIX)
    {
        for (int value : array)
        {
            int digit = (value / placement) % RADIX;
            buckets[digit].add(value);
        }
        int index = 0;
        for (List<Integer> bucket : buckets)
        {
            for (int value : bucket)
            {
                array[index++] = value;
            }
            bucket.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

В данном случае в качестве дополнительной структуры используется массив списков (`buckets`). В рамках оптимизации кода можно использовать только те позиции, которые действительно есть в сортируемых числах, однако это предполагает наличие сравнения, поэтому добавлять его в код я не стал.

---

Существует реализация, в которой в качестве доп. структуры используется просто массив целых чисел (`count`):

```
private static final int RADIX = 10;

public static int[] sort(int[] array)
{
    for (int placement = 1; placement <= 1000 * 1000 * 1000; placement *= RADIX)
    {
        array = sortPlace(array, placement);
    }
    return array;
}

private static int[] sortPlace(int[] array, int placement)
{
    int[] result = new int[array.length];
    int[] count = new int[RADIX];
    for (int value : array)
    {
        int digit = getDigit(value, placement);
        count[digit]++;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < count.length; i++)
    {
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    }
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int digit = getDigit(array[i], placement);
        count[digit]--;
        result[count[digit]] = array[i];
    }
    return result;
}

private static int getDigit(int value, int placement)
{
    return ((value / placement) % RADIX);
}
```

Оригинальный код можно посмотреть [здесь](https://gist.github.com/yeison/5606963).

Answer (score 4):

> Но как отсортировать массив, не используя при этом сравнения?

В такой постановке задачи можно вообще не сильно менять код.

Рассмотрим фрагмент

```
if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
   c = a[i];
   a[i] = a[i + 1];
   a[i + 1] = c;
}
```

После его выполнения `a[i] <= a[i+1]`, если надо их меняют местами. Это же можно сделать

```
    c = a[i] + ((a[i+1] - a[i]) & ((a[i+1] - a[i]) >> 31));
    a[i+1] = a[i+1] + a[i] - c;
    a[i] = c;
```

Как видите `if` нету.

Comment: Вижу - нет. А какая идея стоит за этим? Было бы хорошо в ответе об этом упомянуть. Думаю, не только у меня возникнут проблемы с осознанием того, как это работает.

Comment: @Regent да нету тут идеи. Обычные битовые операции) даже не знаю что описывать.

Comment: Что такое 31? возникнут ли проблемы для x64?

Comment: @vp_arth 31 это 32-1. Для 64 бита нужно будет 63 писать. Но в Java `int` всегда 32 бита, нет?

Comment: @pavel, я и забыл, что это java)